# Enabling internet keys on an old keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm running Windows 10 and I want to use an old, PS/2, Hewlett-Packard Internet/Multimedia keyboard.

Some of the special keys work: the www key brings up the browser, one of the programmable app keys brings up the calculator, and the volume keys work. But the e-mail key doesn't and the other programmable keys don't. There are, of course, no updated drivers for this 1990s keyboard.

Any idea how I can get full functionality out of this keyboard's special buttons?

Thank you,
   Bob

P.S. For people who are wondering why I'm doing this: I have ripped apart an old HP logic analyzer and put modern PC hardware in it. Since my computer case is an old HP instrument, I want to use a keyboard with the circa 1990 HP logo on it. So it's purely for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Without the drivers what you want isn't possible.  Suggest Autokey to recreate the functionality.  No guarantee it will works entirely depends if the email key still sends a key signal without the drivers

Answer (score 0):

You need the drivers in order to map the key to a program. Right now if you press the key the keyboard is likely sending a signal to the computer but it doesn't know what to do with it.
If you can find the old original drivers you might be able to manually install them on Windows 10 (there are alot of variables as to whether this will work or not). You can try a variety of the following:

1) Install the driver using "Compatability Mode" Right click the .exe and choose the Compatability tab. Install as normal.

2) Install the drivers manually (force). Manually extract the *.inf files from the driver package. Go to Device Manager and right click the device and then choose update Driver. Choose "Let me choose" and browse to the folder containing the *.inf files. Afterward you might have to indicate to "show all devices" or something similar.

There are also some programs out there that can try and map the keys for you, depending on how the driver is working. SharpKeys or Autokey are two I have used.

Answer (score 0):

Brian's post made me think of KeyTweak, a key-remapping app similar to SharpKeys, which he mentioned. It has a Half Teach Mode which lets you press the key you want to remap. KeyTweak was able to detect the keyboard's email key, so I remapped it to the standard email key. So now it works.

Thank you.